# How to test exchange server 2007 (or 2010) migrating from 2003, leaving 2003 intact?

Tags: exchange, migration

I want to leave my current exchange server 2003 machine (windows server 2003 in a domain environment) intact, allowing users to continue using that server for mail, etc.

However I want to TEST a different server 2008 machine running exchange 2007 (or possibly 2010).

Ideally I want to be able to copy over all the exchange user information, mail, calendars, etc.   ?

If it all goes smooth I will plan an actual replacement migration/transition.

Answer (score 3):

You could build an isolated virtual environment, convert the physical machines (Exchange and DC) to virtual machines, bring the virtual machines up in the isolated virtual environment, install Exchange Server 2007 or 2010 on a new virtual server in the isolated virtual environment and test your migration/transition.